# Is there a way to find out which elements a certain element overlaps?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom canvas that allows elements to be dragged. However I do not want to allow elements to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could perform a hit test using the **VisualTreeHelper.HitTest** method. Here's more info on that:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters(v=VS.100).aspx

Cheers, Alex